# AppsFlyer SDK Integration Test successful on app, but non-organic test data is not reflected on the Dashboard

Tags: android, appsflyer

I have performed an Integration test with the AppsFlyer's test app, ending with the "Hooray!" success message. However, no non-organic install is reflected in the Dashboard.

Moreover, nothing appears in the dropdown "Media Source" (It should appear AppsFlyer_Test)

AppsFlyer SDK version:4.8.15
AppsFlyer test SDK app version: 4.3.13
Device tested: Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 7.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to whitelist your device? (or try testing on another device?)

Comment: Yes, the device is whitelisted. I have even tried with the two ways: with the app and the web. I have tried with other devices with the same result. (In Oreo devices, the result of the test is fail, but that is another issue)

Comment: @FranJMartínez it's hard to say without knowing the package name you are testing - but it from the Dashboard image it might be a package name mismatch issue (meaning the package name added to the dashboard does not match the package name of the tested app) - if you wish you can submit a support ticket to support@appsflyer.com with more details and we can inspect the issue internally.

The issue with Android O was resolved in Android SDK version v4.8.18 (issues origin is broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts changes in Android O)

Comment: did you manage to fix this?